# how to create a tutorial website use static pages or database

Tags: asp.net, html, sql-server

how to create a tutorial website?

Do i have to create a database to store tutorial contents

or create static pages for all tutorials.

Comment: You can do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to maintain a tutorial website with a CMS. There are different ones available.

In my opinion [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) will suite your needs for the beginning, but it is running on PHP.

If you want something running on asp.net you can give [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) a try.